# holidays storage,how it can be stored?

Tags: database

i am in need to have list of holidays to store in db and calculate business days based on holidays.holidays list will be different for different countries and not same for all years.
so there is need for me to calculate business days between start and end dates as per holidays.start date and end may not be in the same year.
so help me out in this case how db design should be maintained.

Answer (score 1):

Make a table with the holidays per country:

```
CREATE TABLE Holidays
(
  Country INT NOT NULL,
  [Date] DATE NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Holidays PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Country, [Date])
)
```

Then make a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx) to enumerate all days between two dates:

```
WITH Dates ([Date] Date)
AS
(
  SELECT @StartDate
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY, @StartDate, 1)
  FROM Dates Where Dates.Date < @EndDate
)
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Dates
WHERE [Date] NOT IN (SELECT [Date] from Holidays WHERE Country = @CountryCode)
AND DATEPART(WeekDay, [Date]) NOT IN (6,7)
WITH (MAXRECURSION = 10000)
```

That will give you a count of business days. The CTE query builds a list of all dates between @StartDate and @EndDate and then filters out those dates that are listed as holidays for the specific country and isn't weekday number 6 or 7 (which I think maps to saturday and sunday).

Comment: sir it will be helpful if i get little idea about table definitions

Answer (score 0):

Holidays have to be locale- and year-dependent.

If there are rules that govern when holidays fall, perhaps those are better expressed in code.  These can be triggers or stored procedures that you'll use to populate your business calendars each year.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table holidays{
  country_id int,
  name text,
  start_date date,
  end_date date
}default charset=utf8;
```

calculating business days is not straightforward, as you need to define what are business days. for large periods, you could roughly just find the difference in days and multiply by 5/7. for small periods, you would want more precision so should probably do it with programming logic instead.